# Django, build long queryset automatically

Tags: python, django

I've got a model with many fields. I'd like to build a queryset that selects the objects which have blank fields from a predefined list of fields. (Any of the fields, not all)

Say:

```
fields=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']
```

I could write

```
model.objects.filter(Q(a==Null) | Q(b==Null) | Q(c==Null) ...
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
qObj = None
for field in fields:
    newQ = Q(**{field :  Null})
    if qObj is None:
        qObj = newQ
    else:
        qObj = qObj | newQ
```

I don't love the `qObj = None` and following check, but I don't know of a way around it when building up Q objects. The `Q(**{field: Null})` might be what you're looking for generally, however.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
query_terms = {}
for fieldname in fields:
    query_terms['%s__isnull' % fieldname] = False
model.objects.exclude(**query_terms)
```

Or if you're on 2.7 or later, use a dictionary comprehension to build `query_terms`.

Your original query is awkward because it needs to be or'd together - if you instead exclude on the negation you can use the implicit and.

Comment: That is another (probably good) approach: exclude all the results that have no `NULL` field.

Comment: Also a nice straightforward approach, I'll try both see what works best

Answer (score 0):

Pretty obfuscated (plus `reduce()` and `lambda` are being criticized even by BDFL), but should work:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
q_result = reduce(lambda q, name: q | Q(**{name: None}), fields, Q())
```

Then just use it:

```py
model.objects.filter(q_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rethink how the table is designed. Even if you succeed in finding a solution  you will be slap with performance issues.

If you are using PostgreSQL, it comes with HStore.

This link will get you started, [Working with the hstore data type in PostgreSQL 9.0 / 9.1 / 9.2](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2011/11/working-with-the-hstore-data-type-in-postgresql-9-0/) and this library for Django to make use of hstore, [PostgreSQL HStore module integration for django orm](https://github.com/niwibe/djorm-ext-hstore).

Hstore is a key value store, you only store the fields with value.

Comment: I'm not dealing with a great number of records, so shouldn't be an issue. Might be worth adding a boolean field that updates on save depending on the state of certain fields.

Comment: Might be, the solution I have provided is another option when things get a little hairy. You might never know when you need it.